# Large switch statement bucketing system

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, swift

I've finally got a solution for a "weekly streak" bucketing system I've been working on but unfortunately it's resulted in a very large switch statement.

I'm running through a handful of dates and determining by a range of seconds (the length of a week) which bucket that date belongs to.

It's obvious to me that this could be refactored in a programmatic way because of the amount of repetition but I'm not sure where to start. Dictionary? Some kind of sorting algorithm? Recursion?

```
open func weeklyStreakCount(weeklyGoal target: Int) -> Int {
    let endDate = Date()
    let startDate = endDate.startOfWeek!
    let startDateInterval = Double(startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)

    var workoutsPerWeek = [Int: Int]()
    let userWorkouts: [UserWorkoutEntity] = self.userWorkouts(completed: true)

    var numberOfGoodBuckets = 0

    for i in 0...100 {
        workoutsPerWeek.updateValue(0, forKey: i)
    }

    // calculate the time from now to seconds in a week and round to the nearest hundreths to create a bucket for that week
    for userWorkout in userWorkouts {
        let workoutTimeInterval = Double((userWorkout.completionDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow)!)
        let rawBucket = (startDateInterval - workoutTimeInterval) / numberOfSecondsInAWeek

        let bucket = Int(rawBucket * 1000)
        let abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek = 604

        switch bucket {
        case 0 ... abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek:
            workoutsPerWeek[0]! += 1
        case abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek ... (abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 2):
            workoutsPerWeek[1]! += 1
        case abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 2 ... (abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 3):
            workoutsPerWeek[2]! += 1
        case abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 3 ... (abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 4):
            workoutsPerWeek[3]! += 1
        case abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 4 ... (abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 5):
            workoutsPerWeek[4]! += 1
        case abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 5 ... (abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 6):
            workoutsPerWeek[5]! += 1
        case abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 6 ... (abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 7):
            workoutsPerWeek[6]! += 1
        case abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 7 ... (abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 8):
            workoutsPerWeek[7]! += 1
        case abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 8 ... (abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 9):
            workoutsPerWeek[8]! += 1
        case abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 9 ... (abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek * 10):
            workoutsPerWeek[9]! += 1
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    // Run through each bucket and see how many times the user hit their goal
    for i in 0...10 {
        if(workoutsPerWeek[i]! > target) {
            numberOfGoodBuckets += 1
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return numberOfGoodBuckets
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details on what you are doing? Why 10 buckets if a week has 7 days? Where does the "magic number" 604 come from? How is the `times` array defined? How is numberOfSecondsInAWeek calculated? – A *self-contained* compiling example would be helpful.

Comment: Sure thing, I was trying to just hone in on the switch statement but I've updated the code with actual function and variable names.

604 comes from having ~604,000 seconds in a week, but I am trimming it and the end dates down to the first three digits. I suppose this is now unnecessary but a previous iteration I had created could only handle this approach.

Comment: Apparently you seek in which multiple of `abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek` the value of `bucket` falls. If I'm right, then why don't you just divide `bucket` by `abbrNumberOfSecondsInAWeek` and truncate the result to the nearest lower integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would replace the dictionary

```
var workoutsPerWeek = [Int: Int]()
```

by an array. A dictionary *could* be memory-saving if you have "few" keys in a "large range",
e.g. 1, 20, 300, 4000, as a "sparse-array" emulation. But that is not the case here:
The bucket numbers range from 0 to 9, so that an array is more appropriate,
easier to initialize, and easier to access (no forced unwraps needed).

It is unclear in your code how many entries are needed: You
initialize entries for `0...100`, update entries for `0...9`, and finally 
evaluate entries `0...10`. If you want to collect the data for the last 10 weeks then it would be

```
var workoutsPerWeek = Array(repeating: 0, count: 10)
```

Now you can use the computed bucket number as an index into the array and
replace the switch statement by

```
let rawBucket = Int((startDateInterval - workoutTimeInterval) / numberOfSecondsInAWeek)
if rawBucket >= 0 && rawBucket < workoutsPerWeek.count {
    workoutsPerWeek[rawBucket] += 1
}
```

The range check for the bucket number can also be done as

```
if workoutsPerWeek.indices.contains(rawBucket) { ... }
```

There are more things which can be improved: In

```
let workoutTimeInterval = Double((userWorkout.completionDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow)!)
```

the conversion to `Double` is not needed. And what if `completionDate` is `nil`?
Your code would crash in that case.

But my main point of criticism is *how* the bucket is computed. 
**A day does not necessarily have 24 hours.** In regions with daylight saving time,
a day can have 23 or 25 hours if the clocks are adjusted one hour back or forward.
Applied to your code: A week does not necessarily have 604,800 seconds.

The proper way to compute calendar differences is to use the `Calendar` methods
and `DateComponents`:

```
for userWorkout in userWorkouts {
    // Ensure that completionDate is set, otherwise ignore this entry
    guard let completionDate = userWorkout.completionDate else { continue }

    // Compute #of weeks between completionDate and startDate
    let weeksAgo = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekOfMonth], from: completionDate, to: startDate).weekOfMonth!

    // Update corresponding bucket
    if workoutsPerWeek.indices.contains(weeksAgo) {
        workoutsPerWeek[weeksAgo] += 1
    }
}
```

Finally, the calculation of the number of consecutive weeks where the goal has been reached can be simplified to

```
let numberOfGoodBuckets = workoutsPerWeek.prefix(while: { $0 >= target }).count
```